# Visual studio 2012 highlight find function has stopped functioning

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Visual studio normally will find or search for any text that I have highlighted and the pressed ctrl + f, for some odd reason this functionality no longer works.

does anyone know a fix for this issue?

Edit: To clear up below is the current Scenario for my issue.

when I highlight a specific variable and then press Ctrl + F instead of bringing up the find bar with the highlighted variable in it, it brings up the find bar with previously search text

Comment: Can you tell us what specifically isn't happening in this scenario?  Hard to tell from the question

Comment: Close the Visual Studio and start again. It must just be a bug, where Visual Studio cannot recognize the key presses.

Comment: What is happening is when I highlight a specific variable and then press Ctrl + F instead of bringing up the find bar with the highlighted text in it, it brings up the find bar with previously search text

Comment: @Elliott Was wondering did the answer below help you?

Comment: It hasnt appeared to work, but im going to try it again just to double check that what I did was correct

Answer (score 1):

Your default settings might have been changed. Just reset it.

If that does not work;

Go to

> Tools --> Options --> Keyboard  (Try Resetting it here.)
>
> In **Press shortcut keys** text box, press **Ctrl f** and see what
>   **Shortcut currenty used by:** says?
>
> It should be **Edit.Find(Ctrl+F (Global))**

Hope that helps.